# Why nohup outputs process id?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal

When I'm running command `nohup sh script.sh &` in Terminal I have the following output:
`[1] 42603`
`appending output to nohup.out`. Where 42603 is process id of this command, but I don't want to see it. What can I do?

P.S. I'm running OSX Capitan, version 10.11.6

Comment: Close your eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `nohup` in a subshell and redirect the subshell's output to `/dev/null` like this: `(nohup sh script.sh &) >/dev/null` (note that this will also hide any output from `sh script.sh`)

Answer (score 1):

something like this will mute that one line and will keep the script.sh connected to stdout

`nohup sh script.sh & | grep -v nohup.out`

if it is outputting that thing to stderr you will need to redirect to stdout

`nohup sh script.sh 2>&1 & | grep -v nohup.out` maybe the order is wrong there, my shell scripting syntax is usually wrong